# What is a face in 2D?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, game-physics

I've been trying to find the collision point after applying the SAT collision-detection algorithm. Everywhere I look I keep hearing the term "face normal"

- **What is a face normal in 2D?**
- **What is a face in 2D?**

To me, it seems weird to refer to faces in 2D, since it seems like there is only 1 face that's surrounded by edges. Here is one instance where I see the term "Face Direction" and Plane being used[image: Here is one instance where I see the term "Face Direction", "Face Count" and Plane being used]

Comment: In 2D there is no face normal as that requires an extra dimension (making a 3D vector) There is a face (the 2D polygon) which has edges and at least 3 vertices (2D verts), It can be said to be clockwise or counter clockwise which implies a 3D dimension but only abstractly. By face normal they are referring to the edges (a line segment defined by 2 verts) Edge normal is a 2D unit vector perpendicular to an edge.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Thanks for the clarification.